# Azure Service App - configure startup host to use bearer token

Tags: azure, authentication, token, host

I want to host my REST API on Azure Service App with authorization bearer token.
On Azure portal I've done:

1. Create new App Service (testservice).
2. On Authentication/Authorization:

   - App Service Authentication -> On
   - Action to take when request is not authenticated -> Log in with Azure Active Directory. Set Authentication Providers to Active Directory Authentication with Management mode: Express and create new Azure AD Application (register new app: testserviceapp)
   - Token Store -> On
3. On App registrations -> testserviceapp:

   - Authentication -> Web -> Redirect URIs: https://testservice.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
   - Authentication -> Web -> Implicit grant -> Access tokens: true, ID tokens: true
   - Authentication -> Supported account types -> Accounts in this organizational directory only (... - Single tenant)
   - Authentication -> Advanced settings -> Treat application as a public client: No
   - Certificates & secrets -> create new ClientSecret
   - Expose an API -> Add a scope: https://testservice.azurewebsites.net/user_impersonation
   - Expose an API -> Add a scope: https://testservice.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast

Next, I created RestApiService project in VisualStudio and publish into Azure.
appsettings.json in my RestApiService host:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "xxx",
    "AppIDURL": "https://testservice.azurewebsites.net",
    "ConfigView": "API"
  }
}
```

WeatherForecastController.cs:

```
 [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

On client app I successfully get AccessToken:

```
static AuthToken GetToken()
        {
            var uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
            var method = $"{TenantID}/oauth2/token";
            var client = new RestClient(uri);
            var request = new RestRequest($"{uri}{method}", Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", ClientID);
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", ClientSecret);
            request.AddParameter("resource", "https://testservice.azurewebsites.net/");
            return client.Execute<AuthToken>(request).Data;
        }
```

But when I try to call api with this token, I receive 401 Unauthorized error (You do not have permission to view this directory or page.):

```
 static void GetItems(string token)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://testservice.azurewebsites.net/");
        var request = new RestRequest("https://testservice.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"bearer {token}");
        var response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try this request.AddParameter("resource", "https://testservice.azurewebsites.net"); (Removing the slash). It should match the App URL.

Comment: I tried, but the same Unauthorized error.

Comment: Seems like similar issue, Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337449/postman-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page-with-bearer